# javascript float dynamic precision?

Tags: javascript, math, precision, floating

how can I get dynamic precision for float?

exemple what I need :

```
0.00019400000001.dynamicPrecision() //0.000194
0.0001940001.dynamicPrecision()     //0.000194
0.0001941.dynamicPrecision()        //0.0001941
0.0194.dynamicPrecision()           //0.0194
0.01940000.dynamicPrecision()       //0.0194
```

(its important to not have useless zero at the end)

I can't use toFixed or toPrecision because the significative number can change and is unknow. so what way to write this `dynamicPrecision` method with dynamic precision?

Comment: Have you tried something? please post your code

Comment: Also, what would be the output of something like `0.00019401`

Comment: It's unclear what you're wanting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's a bit questionable what you are asking for, one approach would be to take slices of the decimal and then compare it to the original. If it is some threshold percentage different, consider it an answer.

```js
const f = (v, threshold = .9999) => {
  let shift = 1;
  let part;
  
  do {
    shift *= 10;
    part = Math.floor(v * shift) / shift;
  } while (part / v < threshold);
  
  return part;
}

[0.194, 0.194000001, 0.19401, 0.194101]
  .forEach(v => console.log(f(v)));
```

This uses actual math to determine the significant digit.

Basically, for each step, it takes one more digit and compares it against the value. If it is within the threshold, then it will be returned.

For `1.9410001` it would:

part = 1.9
   part = 1.94
   part = 1.941 // part / v > threshold, returned

The threshold is then configurable. `.9999` means it is `99.99%` the same as the original value.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help,

```
var number1 = 0.00019400000001
console.log(parseFloat(number1.toString().replace(/0+[1-9]$/, '')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all endings with at least one zero and one one at the end. Then take the numererical value.

```js
function precision(v) {
    return +v.toString().replace(/0+1$/, '');
}

console.log([0.00019400000001, 0.0001940001, 0.0001941, 0.0194, 0.01940000].map(precision));
```

Comment: yes but does't work with `0.00019410000000000002` for exemple

Comment: please add some more examples.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Number.prototype.dynamicPrecision = function(){
  return parseFloat(this.valueOf().toString().replace(/0+1$/, ''));
}

console.log(
  0.00019400000001.dynamicPrecision(), //0.000194
  0.0001940001.dynamicPrecision(),     //0.000194
  0.0001941.dynamicPrecision(),        //0.0001941
  0.0194.dynamicPrecision(),           //0.0194
  0.01940000.dynamicPrecision()       //0.0194 
)
```

Comment: yes but does't work with `0.00019410000000000002` for exemple